# Calculate NSDate for day after summertime

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate

I just found a but in one of my apps; the problem is that I am calculating the days in a menu using `initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow` and adding the caculation `(day*X)` (`X` meaning the day in question).

However, the night between 27th and 28th of oct the CEST timezone will become CET thus meaning that for one day the time should be calculated by `(day*X)+3600`. However, I do not want to use if cases and believe there should be a better way of dealing with this.

How can I calculate future days with keeping summer/winter time in mind?

My code:

```
    int day = (60*60*24);
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *days1 = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:day];
    NSDate *days2 = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:(day*2)];
    NSDate *days3 = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:(day*3)];
    NSDate *days4 = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:(day*4)];
    NSDate *days5 = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:(day*5)];
    NSDate *days6 = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:(day*6)];
    NSDate *days7 = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:(day*7)];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (NSDate *)dateByAddingXDaysFromToday:(int)days
{
    NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    comps.day = days;
    return [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
}
```

Then you can use:

```
NSDate *days1 = [self dateByAddingXDaysFromToday:1];
//etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are trying to achieve with calculating the date objects. I'm assuming you want to create objects that refer the next seven days, same time as now.

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[components setDay:1];

NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDate *days1 = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:now options:0];
NSDate *days2 = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:days1 options:0];
NSDate *days3 = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:days2 options:0];
....
```